# Next.js: Why my GET function is returning the same result?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, http, next.js

That is the code on app/lang/route.ts

```
let language: Translation;

export async function GET() {
  try {
    return NextResponse.json({ lang: language, message: "Done!" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  try {
    const body = await req.json();
    language = await body;

    return NextResponse.json(
      { lang: body, message: "Language selected successfully!" },
      { status: 201 }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json(
      { message: "Something went wrong!" },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}
```

This is the function I use to fetch the data from /lang/route.ts

```
async function getData() {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/lang");

  if (res.ok) {
    const json = await res.json();
    console.log(json);
    return json;
  }
  console.error("Something went wrong!");
}

const SignUp = async () => {
  const { lang } = await getData();
  console.log(lang);
  return (
     things...
  );
}
```

I made a button, when it's clicked, it calls an async function that uses the POST method

```
  async function setLang(lang: string) {
    const language = await checkLang(lang);
    const response = await fetch("/lang", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(language),
    });
    if (response.ok) {
      console.log("Done!")
    }
  }
```

It works, BUT, there is a problem, the getData function always get the same data, even though, when I go to http://localhost:2000/lang, the data changes like I want.

Comment: because of Next handler caching
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_cJFYZSiDM